# I got downvoted for asking help with a movie that I barely ever remember

Tags: discussion, votes, etiquette, policy

On the [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchagne site, I asked "What is the movie that features a wife killing her husband after finding out he killed many innocent people during the war?" A person commented "High Crimes?", so I searched for High Crimes. It turns out that High Crimes was the movie I looked for.

I read the plot of the movie, and the wife didn't even kill the husband. My memory was so vague that I couldn't even remember details.

I found my post downvoted twice, and I asked why. Someone commented 'The rules here is the "identify" questions must contain as much details as possible'.

This penalizes people who remember little or hardly anything and thus need more help, which is bad. The thing is that the rules don't directly warrant this behavior.

I think rules should be changed so that status attacks are made more difficult. By making it more difficult for anyone to launch status attacks, I think we'll prevent trolls and/or people who exaggerate rules from attacking others.

Comment: What do you mean by "status attack"?

Comment: @Peter most likely OP means downvoters and those voting to close.

Comment: You should include *anything* you remember even if it seems obvious or small. For example: was it black and white or colour? When did you see it? (for example, if you don't know but you were still at school when you saw it, and you're 25 now, that narrows it down by ruling out films made in the last 10 years). What language was it in, and was it dubbed? And then anything about what the characters looked like - were they young adults, or middle-aged, or elderly? ([here's the question in question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44104/) Was the film tense, action-packed, slow, funny?

Comment: For the record, I was one of those who downvoted. I did so because the question was exceptionally sparse and lacking in relevant detail. On the flipside, I voted against the flag raised (VTC "Off topic") because the answer, no matter how badly written, was at least answerable.

Answer (score 10):

Did you see this?

[image]

Probably not, given you didn't use the "identify-this-movie" tag.

But if you *had* seen it, you'd have gotten a link to [this handy wiki](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-movie/info), which advises:

> Post as much information as you can remember about the movie or TV show. Even if the details you can recall are disjointed or incomplete, they are be critical to other users as they try to help.

"Guessing game" questions are notoriously problematic; any time you can narrow down the list of guesses and let folks make an *informed* answer, you should do so. Chances are, the downvotes are a reflection on the brevity of your question.